# How do I use window function to get max price and its id?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have this query

```
select adate, factoryid, purchid, itemname, max(price) as price 
from tableb where catnum = 9
group by adate, factoryid, purchid, itemname
order by adate, factoryid, purchid, itemname
```

But I want the id for that row. So in a perfect world:

```
select id, adate, factoryid, purchid, itemname, max(price) as price 
from tableb where catnum = 9
group by adate, factoryid, purchid, itemname
order by adate, factoryid, purchid, itemname
```

But I know that won't work.

So I tried this:

```
select id, adate, factoryid, purchid, itemname, 
       max(price) over(partition by adate, factoryid, purchid, itemname) as price 
from tableb where catnum = 9
```

That doesn't work. The price is duplicated for all the ids. And the query result set goes from 4000 rows to 11000.

So obviously, I got the window function wrong somehow. First what did I do wrong and secondly, of course, how do I fix it?

Comment: id is not uniquely determined. Do you want all ids or just any one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY adate, factoryid, purchid, itemname ORDER BY price DESC, id DESC) rn
        FROM    tableb 
        WHERE   catnum = 9
        ) q
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use windowed version of `MAX` along with [**FIRST_VALUE**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018%28v=sql.110%29.aspx), available from SQL Server 2012+:

```
SELECT DISTINCT adate, factoryid, purchid, itemname, 
       MAX(price) OVER (PARTITION BY adate, factoryid, purchid, itemname) AS price,
       FIRST_VALUE(id) OVER (PARTITION BY adate, factoryid, purchid, itemname
                             ORDER BY price DESC) AS id
FROM tableb 
WHERE catnum = 9
ORDER BY adate, factoryid, purchid, itemname
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear exactly why you want the id but...
assuming

1. you want all ids for the condition
2. id is a PK of tableb

then this might work:

```
SELECT tableb.* FROM tableb
INNER JOIN
(
select adate, factoryid, purchid, itemname, max(price) as price 
from tableb where catnum = 9
group by adate, factoryid, purchid, itemname
) AS grouped
ON  tableb.adate = grouped.adate AND
    tableb.factoryid = grouped.factoryid AND
    tableb.purchid = grouped.purchid AND
    tableb.itemname = grouped.itemname AND
    tableb.price = grouped.price
order by tableb.adate, tableb.factoryid, tableb.purchid, tableb.itemname
```